# discord.py - How can I edit the last message after a button is clicked? (slash commands)

Tags: python, discord.py

me once again.
I want to make a suggestion command. When someone executes the /suggest command, you can press the confirm button to do it. I want to know how I can edit the previous message on that slash command instead of just making a new one. (ephemeral messages)

code:

```
#Custom View Class
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    #setting up button (you can add multiple such)
    @discord.ui.button(label='Confirm', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # on interaction
        await ctx.response.edit_message("whae")


@bot.tree.command(name="suggest", description="Make a suggestion with this command.")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction, title: str, description: str):
    # add the view to a message
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Is this information correct?", description=f"sdfsdfsdfsd", color=discord.Colour.random())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{ctx.user.avatar.url}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"Title", value=f"{title}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Description", value=f"{description}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"USER ID: {ctx.user.id}")
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=MyView(), ephemeral=True)
```

Does anyone know how? I've searched for 20 minutes and they all just gave me errors. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's make this code a bit more clear:

```
class View(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label='Confirm', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="whae",embed=None,view=None)


@bot.tree.command(name="suggest", description="Make a suggestion with this command.")
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction, title: str, description: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Is this information correct?", description=f"sdfsdfsdfsd", color=discord.Colour.random())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{interaction.user.avatar.url}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"Title", value=f"{title}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Description", value=f"{description}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"USER ID: {interaction.user.id}")
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=View(), ephemeral=True)
```

So the changes:

- (Most important change to me) do not call the interaction  ctx it is really confusing. discord.Interaction is interaction, commands.Context is ctx. It works anyways but looks ugly and unpractical.
- in the edit message function, I made a declaration for the things I want to change

That's it.